# How to sort an array that contains collection in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
[
    {
        "clubName": "FC Nightmare",
        "win": 0,
        "played": 1,
        "draw": 0,
        "lose": 1,
        "gs": 1,
        "ga": 2,
        "gd": -1,
        "points": 0
    },
    {
        "clubName": "Manchester City",
        "win": 1,
        "played": 1,
        "draw": 0,
        "lose": 0,
        "gs": 3,
        "ga": 2,
        "gd": 1,
        "points": 3
    },
    {
        "clubName": "Inter Milan",
        "win": 0,
        "played": 1,
        "draw": 0,
        "lose": 1,
        "gs": 2,
        "ga": 3,
        "gd": -1,
        "points": 0
    },
    {
        "clubName": "AC Milan",
        "win": 1,
        "played": 1,
        "draw": 0,
        "lose": 0,
        "gs": 2,
        "ga": 1,
        "gd": 1,
        "points": 3
    }
]
```

i have this array.i want to sort this array by points.how to do that in laravel??

i've tried this:

> array_multisort(array_column($point_table,'points'),$point_table);

but it doesn't work..

Comment: You can take help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: [Working](https://3v4l.org/piqnl)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel, which your tag suggests, you can use collections to manipulate arrays like this. For example:

```
$array = collect($array)->sortBy('count')->reverse()->toArray();
```

Or

Using array_multisort()

```
$array = array(   
   46 => 
      array (
       'name' => 'HSR Layout',
       'url' => 'hsr-layout',
       'count' => 2,
      ),

   37 => 
      array (
       'name' => 'Electronic City',
       'url' => 'electronic-city',
       'count' => 3,
      )
  );

$price = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row)
{
    $count[$key] = $row['count'];
}
array_multisort($count, SORT_DESC, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: $array = collect($array)->sortBy('count')->reverse()->toArray(); it gives me same array without sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple php-function `usort`.

But also with laravel's collection:

```
collect($point_table)->sortBy('points');
```

Comment: collect($point_table)->sortBy('points');  this returns same array without sorting.can you tell me how to use usort in this case

Comment: Really? That's strange. Can you show your code? My code above will return you new collection with new sorted array. For convert it to array you must use `->toArray()` as @sss-s said.
With `usort` it can be like: `usort($point_table, function($a, $b) { if ($a['points'] == $b['points']) return 0; return ($a['points'] > $b['points']) ? -1 : 1; });`. After that, your $point_table will be contained with new sorted array.